# How to prevent "MetaMask Ether Faucet Error 500" when retrieving one ether?

Tags: metamask

I am not able to request 1 ether from faucet.metamask.io. When I open the metamask extension it says connected, regardless. I also removed AdBlocker from this page. On top of that, I tried other faucets and they failed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Error 500]

Comment: I wasn't able to get any testnet either from Ropsten or Goerli.

Comment: I'm having the same issue